# TFS query condition on both parent item AND child item

Tags: search, tfs

We have Product Backlog Items with child tasks items in TFS. I need to find closed Product Backlog Items with child tasks that are NOT closed. I.e. (Type=Task and State<>Closed) and (Parent State=Closed).

I've tried this:

**Filter for top level**:
State In: Done; Removed; Closed; Rejected;

**Filter for linked work Items**:
State Not In: Done; Removed; Closed; Rejected;

Match linked work items first

[Query definition](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6hN5r.png)

But it does not work. It returns all tasks that are not "Done" even if the Parent is not done either. In these cases it just hide the parent. I only want the list to contain the "not closed" child items for "closed" Parent items.

Is this possible at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set the type of query to **Work items and direct links**. And the **Filter options** set to **Only return items that have matching links**.

Please refer to below screenshot. Check the document [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/queries/using-queries?view=azure-devops#use-direct-links-to-view-dependencies) for more information.

[image]

Comment: Brilliant! Exactly what I needed. Thanks a lot.